# AJAX stay on same page after submit, output on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have some drop downs looks like this in my HTML form:

```
<form name="fee" method="POST" action="">
<p><span class="title">Number of artists:</span>
    <select name="Number">
        <option value="" rel="none" selected disabled>Please select an option..</option>
        <option value="one" rel="one_art">One artist only</option>
        <option value="more" rel="more_arts">More than one artists</option>
</p>
```

A table of summery will be generated after I click the submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
```

My question is: Whenever I click the button, the previously selected option will be reset. And only the summery show up at the end of the page. Is there a way to output the summery on the same page without the previously selected option gets cleared?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check the value of `Name` then `echo  "selected"` on the value that matches the dropdown...or use Ajax as you have noted in your title.

Comment: you need to use verify statement for select and at the children option you have to echo the selected attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use AJAX POST to post the form data, and JQuery to keep the same option selected:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#fee").on('submit',(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var selectedOption = $( "#Number option:selected" ).text();

                        $.ajax({
                           url: "here put the url to the php page handling your form data", 
                           type: "POST",
                           data: new FormData(this),
                           contentType: false,
                           cache: false,
                           processData: false,
                           success: function ()
                           {
                              $("#Number").val(selectedOption);

                           }
                        });
                    }
                });
```